# I can't retrieve my contacts from Google

Tags: contacts

I can't retrieve my contacts from Google I back them up with my old phone I've got a new phone and it won't give them to me

Answer (score 0):

Clear app data of Contacts, restart. If that doesn't work, remove Google account from phone, clear data of Google Play Services, restart, sign in.